# How would I create something similar to the Minecraft Server Console in python3

Tags: python, console-application

I'm messing around with some networking stuff and I wanted the server to be able to issue commands, namely a "stop" command. The idea was to create something similar to the minecraft server console. The issue is that when using threading, there are a few problems with just using `print()` and `input()`

[Image](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-NWvR5jYrBNo/UyBo0lN_2xI/AAAAAAAABNI/mBoXz5C358c/s1600/craftbukkit-console.png) of the Minecraft Server Console incase you dont know what I mean.

I tried to research a few things but found nothing good. I was trying to learn curses but I'm not sure how helpful it would be. I decided before I go any further I would ask on stack overflow before wasting any more time with research (I've been trying to figure this out for 2-3 days now)

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: I don't get what your question is...  you're trying to send *actual commands into a Minecraft server*, or just create a small terminal app that looks like that?  First thing that comes to mind is [Love2D's simple example](https://love2d.org/wiki/lua-enet) of how to network.  I know it's Lua, but you could do a similar thing in Python.

Comment: @Doyousketch2 sorry, my bad, I meant that I wanted to make a terminal app that looks similar to the Minecraft Server Console.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to go thru with learning basic curses.

I was able to make this test code and modify for my application

```py
import curses,time
import curses.textpad

def main(screen):
    h,w = screen.getmaxyx()
    window = curses.newwin(h-2,w,0,0)
    window.scrollok(True)
    InputContainer = curses.newwin(1,w,h-1,0)
    inputWindow = curses.newwin(1,w-2,h-1,2)
    inputField = curses.textpad.Textbox(inputWindow,insert_mode=True)
    InputContainer.addstr('> ')
    window.addstr(0,0,"Console Application started\n")
    screen.refresh()
    InputContainer.refresh()
    window.refresh()
    running = True
    while running:
        rows, cols = screen.getmaxyx()
        userIn = inputField.edit()[0:-1]
        if userIn!="":
            if str(userIn)=="stop":
                running = False
            window.addstr(f"Command Issued: {userIn}\n")
        inputWindow.refresh()
        inputWindow.clear()
        window.refresh()

curses.wrapper(main)
```

Feel free to use this yourself.